# Github desktop - Auto generated merge commit every time I run pull

Tags: git, github-desktop

I use Github desktop, most recent version. Starting last week, every time I pull changes from remote branch or master, a new merge commit is auto generated with exactly same changes I just pulled. There is no conflict on any files.

I tried to add gitconfig pull.ff=only but it didnt work for me.

Any help?

Comment: i'm having the same issue, here what i found abount this subject : https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/3422

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there are changes on the remote branch that aren't on your local one, and changes on your local branch that aren't on the remote. To avoid the merge commit, do a fetch, then rebase your local branch on top of the remote rather than pulling.

### Why this happens

To understand this behavior, it helps to think of what would happen if you had two local branches and wanted to merge one into the other. If you want to merge B into A, and there are no commits in A that aren't in B, then git will do a fast forward merge, and you won't get any merge commit. However, if A has diverged (has a commit that is not in B), then merging B into A will create a merge commit, unless you rebase B onto A first.

Comment: i'm having the same issue, but my local branch do not have changes on it, after github desktop pull the code, it creates a merge commit, i don't understand why because my local branch is exacly the same from last time, there is not pending changes but it create a merge commit anyway, it only happens on my notebook, not on my desktop, so i believe its a configuration.

Comment: Never figured out why this happens, but the same thing keeps happening to me, no matter if I use rebase or ff config.